# Test script in Postman

Tags: postman, postman-testcase

I'd like to print a field from the body request after the request itself, in order to print a string build like this: `requestFied, + responseField, + timeStamp.`

I have tried with `pm.request.json().field_name` but doesn't work.

Comment: If you're sending a JSON body, you can access it using `pm.request.body`. To get a specific field, you'll need to parse the body as JSON first. After parsing the JSON body, you can extract the specific field you need. Once you have the response, you can access a specific field from it, assuming the response is in JSON format.

Comment: Great! I've tried with 

var request = JSON.parse(pm.request.body);

var orderId = request.orderNumber;

and works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adding body ?

```
pm.request.body.json()
```